# Autocomplete with google map api with google map in Xamarin android

Tags: google-maps, google-api, xamarin.android

I tried [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37424/autocomplete-google-api) link , but I was not able to find the below classes.

```
GoogleMapPlaceClass ;
GeoCodeJSONClass ;
```

What I am trying to do is to use Autocomplete to search a place and when I am done with the place name, the marker must be seen on the Google map on the mobile screen.

Could anyone please help me or tell me where can I find this class?

Thanks

Comment: its his custom classes you cannot find them anywhere except where he kept it anyways follow this guide and things will work i hope http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2015/05/google-place-api-with-autocomplete-in.html

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time and I came back again to this problem and I realized that the data sent from the Google MAP API is of json format and I was waiting for someone to come with the class. It hit me that I can convert the String json data to its class object free online.

So I pasted the written data into [jsonToCsharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and I got the required classes. Below I have posted the class structure so that anyone can use it for Google MAP API for Autocomplete in Xamerin Andriod or any other platform.

Class of GoogleMapPlaceClass & GeoCodeJSONClass.

```
    public class MatchedSubstring
{
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class MainTextMatchedSubstring
{
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class StructuredFormatting
{
    public string main_text { get; set; }
    public List<MainTextMatchedSubstring> main_text_matched_substrings { get; set; }
    public string secondary_text { get; set; }
}

public class Term
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<MatchedSubstring> matched_substrings { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public StructuredFormatting structured_formatting { get; set; }
    public List<Term> terms { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class GoogleMapPlaceClass
{
    public List<Prediction> predictions { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}


public class AddressComponent
{
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast2 northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest2 southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class GeoCodeJSONClass
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

[link of how to implement Autocomplete with google map api with google map in Xamarin android](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37424/autocomplete-google-api)
Thanks,